# Ansible, vmware_guest and mounting a disk

Tags: ansible, centos, vmware

I'm using ansible and the `vmware_guest` module to spin up VMs.

Specifically, I'm creating VMs from a template, like so:

```
- name: Deploy VM from template
  vmware_guest:
    annotation: "{{ lookup('template', './templates/annotations.j2') }}"
    hostname: '{{ deploy_vsphere_host }}'
    username: '{{ deploy_vsphere_user }}'
    password: '{{ deploy_vsphere_password }}'
    validate_certs: no
    datacenter: '{{ deploy_vsphere_datacenter }}'
    esxi_hostname: '{{ deploy_vsphere_cluster }}'
    folder: '{{ deploy_vsphere_folder }}'
    name: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    guest_id: '{{ guest_id }}'
    disk:
    - size_gb: '{{ disk_size }}'
      type: thin
      datastore: '{{ deploy_vsphere_datastore }}'
    networks:
    - name: '{{ guest_network }}'
      start_connected: true
      allow_guest_control: true
      ip: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      netmask: '{{ guest_netmask }}'
      gateway: '{{ guest_gateway }}'
      dns_servers:
      - '{{ guest_dns_server }}'
    hardware:
      memory_mb: '{{ guest_memory }}'
      num_cpus: '{{ guest_vcpu }}'
    customization:
      dns_servers:
      - '{{ guest_dns_server }}'
      domain : '{{ guest_domain_name }}'
      hostname: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    template: '{{ guest_template }}'
    wait_for_ip_address: yes
    wait_for_customization: yes
    state: "{{ state }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

However, the disk is not automatically mounted.

For example, I'm adding a 1000GB disk, using the `{{ disk_size }}`. When I ssh to the VM, I get the following details:

## lsblk

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0               2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda               8:0    0 1000G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0   15G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0 13.4G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0  1.6G  0 lvm  
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

## df -h

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   14G   12G  2.3G  84% /
devtmpfs                  12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     12G  2.3M   12G   1% /run
tmpfs                     12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               1014M  189M  826M  19% /boot
tmpfs                    2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /run/user/1000
```

## fdisk

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1073.7 GB, 1073741824000 bytes, 2097152000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a708c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    33554431    15727616   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 14.4 GB, 14382268416 bytes, 28090368 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 1719 MB, 1719664640 bytes, 3358720 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

## blkid

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root: UUID="1f352c63-6b7d-4005-89ce-a0dbc149d2e0" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="KvUYqI-biVh-jl4C-yi2F-ZPtK-Fokq-1CHzwH" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="cdaaa519-be25-4ada-badb-28edbfae5750" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/mapper/centos-swap: UUID="c614ac9a-665f-4a0c-bd13-31c377db3c43" TYPE="swap"
```

## Question

What is the best way, using Ansible, to mount and use the 1000gb disk?

Answer (score -1):

i think module vmware_guest_disk help you.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information on your proposed solution? Thank you.

Comment: create disk with this module, then mount them with lvm module, like he - https://github.com/zaxos/lvm-ansible-role/tree/master/tasks

Comment: Please edit and improve your answer with this explanation and the github link.